# A workaround to converting a number to the same amount of hashtags?

Tags: python

Very new to programming so please forgive my ignorance:

```
number = int(input("Input the number of # you want."))
hashtag = 1
total = (number * hashtag)
while hashtag != total: 
print("#")
hashtag = hashtag + 1
```

If i enter 4 for example, 3 hashtags will be printed, and i can't find an alternative so that i can display 4 hashtags instead.

Comment: Set `hashtag = 0`.

Comment: `for _ in range(number): print('#')`?

Comment: Please pay attention to indents following blocks (your print and increment statements seem incorrectly indented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a really cool language. You can write this in lots of ways. Here is a one liner:

```py
number = int(input("Input the number of # you want."))
print("#" * number)
```

Another way with a for loop:

```py
number = int(input("Input the number of # you want."))
for i in range(number):
    print("#", end="")  # end="" means no newline, print all in the same line
```

Another way with a while loop:

```py
number = int(input("Input the number of # you want."))
counter = 0
while(counter != number):
    print("#", end="")
    counter += 1
```

If you want a newline at the end of each #, add a '\n', like this

1st: `print("#\n" * number)`

2nd and 3rd: `print("#")` (just remove the end="")

Answer (score 1):

```py
number = int(input("Input the number of # you want."))
print("#\n"*number)
```

Comment: The [string multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545587/multiply-string-by-number-python) is an __idiomatic way__ of repeating strings in Python, like `print('#' * 3)` prints `###`.

Comment: Yes but the author wanted each hashtag in a separate line so `'#\n'` is needed

Comment: This was just to give a simple example and explain the language-feature. Usually code-only answers are considered bad quality ;-)